# Persistent tag highlights when changing between buffers

Tags: highlight, tags

I've put following code in my vimrc.

```
function ExtraHighlights()
    let list = taglist('.*')
    for item in list
        if item.kind == 's' || item.kind == 't' || item.kind == 'u' || item.kind == 'g'
            exec 'syntax keyword TagType '.item.name
        elseif item.kind == 'f'
            exec 'syntax keyword TagFunction '.item.name
        elseif item.kind == 'd' || item.kind == 'e'
            exec 'syntax keyword TagDefine '.item.name
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <C-h> :call ExtraHighlights()<CR>
```

It basically generates new syntax keywords for the current buffer based on tags collected by `ctags`. I pick up those keywords in my color theme. If I generate keywords for buffer **A**, then open another buffer **B** in the same window and then come back to original buffer **A**, the keywords are gone and I need to regenerate them.

Is there a way to make it permanent for the current vim session? I tried to call this function from `BufEnter` autocmd, but it's too slow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I generate keywords for buffer A, then open another buffer B in the same window and then come back to original buffer A, keywords are gone and I need to regenerate them

Actually the problem is not that you switched from the buffer A, but is that the buffer A was unloaded by Vim. And upon unloading buffer contents Vim also disposes its syntax elements (and many other things).

So all you have to do is to keep your buffer loaded in memory even after its last window is closed (or occupied by another buffer). Whether you choose `setlocal bufhidden=hide` or `setglobal hidden` doesn't matter.